# Pass Image as file to an ImageField without saving

Tags: python, django, django-models, wand, magickwand

I have a model, lets call it `FooModel`, that has an image field of type `models.Imagefield`.

I'm also using `wand.image` to do some transformation and resizing to an image before I add it to the `FooModel.image` field.

So I have something along this line:

```
foo = FooModel()
with Image(file='path/to/image.png') as tmpImage:
  # some transformation on tmpImage
  file_name = 'newTmpFile.png'
  tmpImage.save(filename=file_name)

  f = open(file_name, 'rb')
  foo.image.save('new_file_name.png', File(f), save=True)
```

So I basically do my transformation, save the image to a temporary place, open it again and pass it to my model's field. This seems extremely redundant and unnecessary, but I haven't managed to pass the `tmpImage` to the `FooModel` instance.

I've tried `File(tmpImage)`, just `tmpImage`, but nothing works. Any other ideas?